# Hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n $ has dimension $n-1$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

A hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by 
\begin{align}
H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x = p + a_1 y_1 + \dots + a_{n-1} y_{n-1}; a_1,\dots,a_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}\}
\end{align}
such that $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent. Now the claim is that this hyperplane is $n-1$ dimensional. But why is this so? For example could $p$ be linearly independent from $y_1,\dots,y_{n-1}$ and hence the hyperplane would be $n$ dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though $p$ is linearly independent from the set $y_i$, we are not taking linear combinations of $p$ : as you can see , you cannot take scalar combinations of $p$, like $2p$ and so on : these will not belong to the hyperplane.

In other words, $x = p+\sum a_iy_i$ is spanned by only $n-1$ elements. *It is not a subspace* : $0$  will not belong to it if $p \neq 0$. However, the dimension of the subspace spanned by the $y_i$ is $n-1$, and this hyperplane is a translate (to $p$) of that subspace, hence as an affine space also has dimension $n-1$.